# How would I sum a multi-dimensional array in the most succinct python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sum

The closest was this one [summing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223043/how-do-i-sum-the-columns-in-2d-list).

So I'll do something similar in my question:

Say I've a Python 2D list as below:

```
my_list =  [ [1,2,3,4],
             [2,4,5,6] ]
```

I can get the row totals with a list comprehension:

```
row_totals = [ sum(x) for x in my_list ]
```

In one line, how can I sum the entire 2d-array?

```
27
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do as easy as

```
sum(map(sum, my_list))
```

or alternatively

```
sum(sum(x) for x in my_list))
```

and call it a day, if you don't expect more than 2 dimensions. Note that the first solution is most likely not the fastest (as in execution time) solution, due to the usage of `map()`. Benchmark and compare as necessary.

Finally, if you find yourself using multidimensional arrays, consider using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and its superior array-friendly functions. Here's a short excerpt for your problem:

```
import numpy as np

my_list = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [2,4,5,6]])
np.sum(my_list)
```

This would work for any number of dimensions your arrays might have.

Comment: `map` is not inherently slow.

Comment: @katrielalex: The numbers disagree with you: http://ideone.com/4RXfR vs http://ideone.com/6tOEJ

Comment: @Marcin you're missing the point -- if you use a _list_ comprehension then the advantage of `map` goes away. Otherwise it allocates an unnecessary list.

Comment: @katrielalex No, I don't think I am missing the point. In a fair comparison, map is faster. In fact, you can check those links again - I've updated them to use sum of map vs sum of generator expression.

Comment: youve got a typo in your solution

Answer (score 4):

Another solution using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_list = [ [1,2,3,4], [2,4,5,6] ]
>>> sum(chain(*my_list))
27
```

Comment: What does the * stands for?

Comment: It's the "unpacking operator" (`*` for lists/tuples, `**` for dictionaries): https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> sum ( [ sum(x) for x in [[1,2,3,4], [2,4,5,6]] ] )
27
```

Comment: Use a generator not a list comprehension (`()` not `[]`).

Comment: @katrielalex: you are right, as well as mindcorrosive. I took OP code to test, then forgot to remove squares.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3,4], [2,4,5,6]]
>>> sum(chain.from_iterable(my_list))
27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum to first add the inner lists together and then sum the resulting flattened list:

```
>>> my_list = [ [1,2,3,4], [2,4,5,6] ]

>>> sum(my_list, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6]

>>> sum(sum(my_list, []))
27
```

Comment: Does your answer add anything on top of the other answers here?