# Strange bevahiour of Python when adding up all elements in a matrix

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, matrix, sum

I have an empty matrix in Python 2.7:

```
self.board = {}
N = 2
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        self.board[i, j] = 0
```

Now I want to add up all elements of the matrix. So I googled how to do it:

```
print sum(map(sum, self.board))
```

[How would I sum a multi-dimensional array in the most succinct python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497290/how-would-i-sum-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-the-most-succinct-python)

Suprisingly, it prints out *4* - the sum of all indexes. Why is that? How can I sum the elements correctly?

Comment: `self.board` is a `dict`. You need to do `sum(self.board.values())` to get the sum. I dunno what you are trying to do, but dictionary is not the correct DS to represent a matrix. Use list of lists, rather.

Comment: ```sum(board.values())```

Comment: @Bhargav Rao, thanks. I confused  lists with dictionaries.