# How to Count columns from a 3x3 square

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a magic Square function out of 2d list: [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]], where It checks if all the columns adds up to 15 from a 3x3 square. I'm stuck on how to write function checks for the sum of columns if anyone can help out that will be highly appreciative. Without using numpy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223043/how-do-i-sum-the-columns-in-2d-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sum the columns in 2D list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223043/how-do-i-sum-the-columns-in-2d-list)

Answer (score 0):

you can use zip function if all the sublist having same length. zip will return tuple of one element from each sub list.

check below answer:

```
a = [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]
col_totals = [ sum(x) for x in zip(*a) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension and sum functions can solve your problem.

E.G:

```
sq = [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]
for i in range(len(sq)):
    print(sum([x[i] for x in sq]))
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be compare the two answers thus far and pick the performance and readability answer  and write a test for the method ensuring people do not break it.